# TypeScript template literal type to match Title Case

Tags: string, typescript, template-literals

I'm working on a template literal type that'd only match title cased strings. I thought I'd first create a single word matcher using `Uppercase<>`:

```js
const uppercaseWord: Uppercase<string> = 'U';
```

but it seems to match lowercase letters too:

```js
const uppercaseWord: Uppercase<string> = 'u';
```

this one won't throw.

I've tried parametrizing it:

```js
type SingleUpperCase<Str extends string> = `${Uppercase<Str>}`;

const upperCaseWord: SingleUpperCase = 'U';
```

But the type argument could not be inferred. It works by passing a string literal explicitly:

```js
type SingleUpperCase<Str extends string> = `${Uppercase<Str>}`;

const upperCaseWord: SingleUpperCase<'u'> = 'U';
```

it works, but I'd need something more generic. Something that matches any uppercase string. If I tried again passing `string` as the type argument, the error is resolved, but the lowercase letter can be assigned without an error:

```js
type SingleUpperCase<Str extends string> = `${Uppercase<Str>}`;

const upperCaseWord: SingleUpperCase<string> = 'u'; // no error
```

I wonder if this is even possible given it'd require a regex-like string matching from the compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside: I'm not exactly sure what rules you have for "title case"; I don't know if `"HTML String"` is in title case or not. For what follows, I will assume that you just need to make sure that the first character of the string and the first character after every space `(" ")` is not lowercase.  That means `"HTML String"` is fine.  If you have a different rule, you can adjust the code in the answer below.

---

There is no specific type in TypeScript that represents title-cased `string`s.  [Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) don't give this to you; while [`Uppercase<string>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype) and [`Capitalize<string>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype) are now their own types as of TypeScript 4.8, implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47050), they won't enforce handle the spacing requirements.

For a true title-case `string` type you would need, as you said, something like regular expression validated `string` types.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) asking for use cases for such regex-validated types; if the solution below doesn't meet your needs, you might want to comment on that issue with your use case, why it is compelling, and why the alternative solutions don't suffice.

---

While there is no *specific* type that works here, you can write a [recursive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) template literal type `TitleCase<T>` which can be used as a *constraint* on `T`.  Meaning that `T extends TitleCase<T>` if and only if `T` is a title-cased string.

Then, in order to save people from having to annotate their strings with some generic type, you'd write a helper function like `asTitleCase()` which just returns its input, but produces a compiler error if you pass in a bad string.

So, while your *ideal* solution here would look like this:

```
/* THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE
const okay: TitleCase = "This Is Fine"; // okay
const error: TitleCase = "This is not fine"; // error
const alsoError: TitleCase = String(Math.random()); // error
*/
```

the *implementable* solution looks like this:

```
const okay = asTitleCase("This Is Fine"); // no error
const error = asTitleCase("This is not fine"); // error!
// ---------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"This is not fine"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '"This Is Not Fine"'.

const alsoError = asTitleCase(String(Math.random())); // error!
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
// '"Please Use a Title Cased String Literal Here, Thx"'
```

Again, this is what is implementable, not what is ideal.  All uses of title-cased string types will need to gain an extra generic type parameter.

Note that you probably don't need to actually write `asTitleCase(...)` unless you want to see the error right at the declaration.  Presumably you have some function (say, `lookupBookTitle()`) that cares about title case. If so, you'd just make *that* function generic and enforce the constraint there.  So instead of `const str = asTitleCase("XXX"); lookupBookTitle(str);`, you'd just write `const str = "XXX"; lookupBookTitle(str);` The only difference is where the error shows up.

Also, inside the implementation of something like `lookupBookTitle()`, you should probably just widen the input to `string` and just treat it as if it's already been validated.  Even though `T extends TitleCase<T>` has the effect of enforcing the constraint on callers, the compiler won't be able to follow the logic when `T` is an unspecified generic type parameter:

```
// callers see a function that constrains title to TitleCase
function lookupBookTitle<T extends string>(title: VerifyTitleCase<T>): Book;

// implementer just uses string
function lookupBookTitle(title: string) {  
  const book = db.lookupByTitle(title); 
  if (!book) throw new Error("NO BOOK");
  return book;
}
```

---

Anyway, here's the implementation:

```
type TitleCase<T extends string, D extends string = " "> =
  string extends T ? never :
  T extends `${infer F}${D}${infer R}` ?
  `${Capitalize<F>}${D}${TitleCase<R, D>}` : Capitalize<T>;
```

The type `TitleCase<T, D>` splits the string `T` at the delimiter `D`, and capitalizes (first character is uppercased) each piece.  So it turns a string into a title-cased version of itself:

```
type X = TitleCase<"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.">
// type X = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog."
```

Then we can write a `VerifyTitleCase<T>` type that checks if `T extends TitleCase<T>`.  If so, it resolves to `T`.  If not, it resolves either to `TitleCase<T>`, or some hard-coded error string that hopefully gives users an idea what went wrong.  (There are no "`throw` types" or "`Invalid` types" in TypeScript, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689); so using a hard-coded error string literal is a workaround):

```
type VerifyTitleCase<T extends string> = T extends TitleCase<T> ? T :
  TitleCase<T> extends never ? "Please Use a Title Cased String Literal Here, Thx" :
  TitleCase<T>
```

And finally, the helper function:

```
const asTitleCase = <T extends string>(s: VerifyTitleCase<T>) => s;
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=2#code/PQKgBAsAUAxg9gOwM4BcxwNYEMCeAuMAFQEsUAbAUwGEskKwBeMAIkIAtikwBJLgMWIIKzANxhgwdNhzR4yNBQBOiuIoIly1WvSasOXTmARw0AM0HCxEsEpWLZiVGCxkkcAKLLV60pRp1GMABlFEVBAHMACgBZLBQ2ADpFLAQAEzgAW0iASmyrSVtVaBBgaGgUHAAHeg0-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)

Comment: Sorry about the loose problem description, what I meant is that every word in the string should start with a capital letter, no restriction on the rest of the word. Ultimately what I needed is compilation time static checks for string parameters of a function, your proposed solution does it perfectly.